# How to hide the automator application icon when running

Tags: sourceforge-appscript

I create a automator application and set it to run at logon, and I check the "Hide" box, but it still shows up (the gear icon) in the status bar. How can I hide it?

I check the "Hide" box here:

[image]

but the gear icon is still shown (the worse part is that it never stops rotating!)

[image]

Is it possible to hide this icon, or let it stop rotating?

Answer (score 0):

`control-click` on it, and choose Show Package Contents from the pop-up menu. Inside the Contents folder, open up Info.plist, and change LSUIElement from No to Yes (if using Property List Editor) — or change the line after the LSUIElement key line to (if using a text editor). Save Info.plist.
Now when the alarm triggers, the Automator plugin will run in the background, without a Dock icon or a menu bar, and the focus will remain on the application you’re using.

Three things to note:

- You might have to move the plug-in out of the iCal folder and back in
  for this to work. Tiger caches the LSUIElement info; moving the app
  forces Tiger to renew the cache.
- You probably do not want to do this with any iCal plugin that has
  dialogs or requires user interaction! This works best for maintenance
  actions, automated downloads, and that sort of thing.
- Third, this will work with any Automator workflow that is saved as an
  application, not just with iCal plugins.”

Then Clear your Cache

Comment: It seems the LSUIElement is already Yes in the plist file. The key in the plist file is ` <key>LSUIElement</key>
 <true/>`

Comment: I removed the folders `/Library/Caches` and `~/Library/Caches` but it doesn't work. Do you mean remove those folders when you say "Clear your Cache" ? Thanks.

Comment: I mean the deleting whats inside the Cache folders. But if this didn't worke'd, idk :(